# Navigation Drawer Does Not Use R.drawable.ic_drawer or swipe closed

Tags: java, android, android-drawable, navigation-drawer

I just added a navigation drawer to my app however it seems as if the `R.drawable.ic_drawer` and `R.drawable.drawer_shadow` aren't being used (it is simply showing a black background instead of the grey one in ic_drawer).

The other issue I'm having is the navigation drawer will open - but does not seem to close unless I hit the back button.

I used the following example:

http://hmkcode.com/android-creating-a-navigation-drawer/

but right now I'm attempting to figure out how to modify the following to get it to close when swiping it from right to left.

### SCREENSHOT:

[image]

### JAVA:

```
    public class Home extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener,
YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener {

    public static final String API_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    public static final String VIDEO_ID = "o7VVHhK9zf0";
    public static final String VIDEO1_ID = "xVHHJqntuXI";
    public static final String VIDEO2_ID = "YWteQj_q3Ro";
    public static final String VIDEO3_ID = "83ZgtqTw-mI";
    public static final String VIDEO4_ID = "n5wMza29JwI";
    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
    private YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView1;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView2;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView3;
    private YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView4;
    private String[] drawerListViewItems;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView drawerListView;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader;
    ScrollView mainScrollView;
    Button fav_up_btn1;
    Button fav_dwn_btn1;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);


        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_custom_view_home);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        // get list items from strings.xml
        drawerListViewItems = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);

        // get ListView defined in activity_main.xml
        drawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        drawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_listview_item, drawerListViewItems));

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, /* host Activity */
                drawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open, /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close /* "close drawer" description */
                );
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        mainScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.groupScrollView);

        youTubeThumbnailView1 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview1);
        youTubeThumbnailView1.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        fav_up_btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fav_up_btn1);

        fav_up_btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean favIsUp = fav_up_btn1
                        .getBackground()
                        .getConstantState()
                        .equals(getResources().getDrawable(
                                R.drawable.fav_up_btn1).getConstantState());
                // set the background
                fav_up_btn1
                .setBackgroundResource(favIsUp ? R.drawable.fav_dwn_btn1
                        : R.drawable.fav_up_btn1);
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO1_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView2 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview2);
        youTubeThumbnailView2.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO2_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView3 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview3);
        youTubeThumbnailView3.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO3_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }
        });

        youTubeThumbnailView4 = (YouTubeThumbnailView) findViewById(R.id.youtubethumbnailview4);
        youTubeThumbnailView4.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        youTubeThumbnailView4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg1) {
                if (youTubePlayer != null) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(VIDEO4_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    mainScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, 0);
                }
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

        youTubePlayer = player;

        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView,
            YouTubeInitializationResult error) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnailView,
            YouTubeThumbnailLoader thumbnailLoader) {

        youTubeThumbnailLoader = thumbnailLoader;
        thumbnailLoader
        .setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(new ThumbnailLoadedListener());

        youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VIDEO_ID);

    }

    private final class ThumbnailLoadedListener implements
    YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0, ErrorReason arg1) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView arg0, String arg1) {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // call ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(), if it returns
        // true
        // then it has handled the app icon touch event
        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the below code:

```
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener


        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.action_settings,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.action_settings  /* "close drawer" description */
                )
```

See if it works.
Also check whether the ic_drawer image is present in drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xxhdpi folders in different sizes.

Comment: I tried it... I'm getting an error stating "DrawerItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: Any suggestions? I don't see  DrawerItemClickListener method in your example.

Comment: I am just showing part of the code that enables the menu icon and shadow, if you are facing issues with adapter or click listener then let me know.

Comment: I updated my source above - it still looks exactly the same (it does not use the ic_drawer image for the drawer)

Comment: Help! : ) (any other suggestions?)

Comment: Where have you placed the ic_drawer images ?

Comment: in the res/drawable-mdpi folder

Comment: Try placing it in all folder as I mentioned in the edited answer. There is no reason your code should not work. Check the logcat for all messages relating to your application. You are bound to find some error in it.

Comment: Also go through this : http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
   @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        actbardrawertoggle.syncState();
    }
```